Similar matrices and linear transform
background finished linear algebra one currently learning algebra 2
to my understanding the idea behind similar matrices is,
a finite vector space can have an infinite number of basis(because of there order or the space of a vector and replace the vector a linear combination can also sometimes replace a vector ) (if we are not talking about the zero vector space where the basis is the empty group )
and when we change the way we look at the vector space we are going from into the other vector space and look at each   coordinate vector representation  so making it a transformation from  $F^n$ to  $F^m$  instead of from matrix vector space to polynomials of order 2 and below then we get that the liner transformation can now be represented in a matrix form in accordance to the bases chosen for input and output
and similar matrices for the same linear operator basically say these two linear transformation are the same thing but we are looking at them from different perspective so applying them to a vector would result in the same result yet in different basis so
we can keep changing between the two
if we can find 2 matrices that indeed have a change of base matrix thats allows us to change between the two then we know they represent the same linear transformation from V to V
at least that's the only intuition that I has gained from linear algebra 1 and the start of 2  , is there something I am missing ?
and the other part of the question is working the way upwards it is clear that 2 matrices have to have same determinant  and the same rank to be similar but  that thats not enough to deduce similarity I can't think of a way to guess intuitively  this matrix similar to that matrix , I can think of a way to reach a similar matrix by multiplying by a matrix that is invertible on both sides  though that does not help much since I am not reaching an optimal representation of the transformation matrix I just reached one of the possible representation , and if I am lucky it is diagonalizable and so I can reach a matrix that makes understanding what the result would look like and what happens to the vector in accordance to the bases in question

I think that the one basic concept that keeps reappearing in all of those topics is coordinates vector in relation to spanning so basically how to think of the vector as a linear combination of the basis represented by the coefficients of the linear combinations and then connecting this to change of basis matrix before focusing on what is a linear transformation and I keep going back to it every now and then so it is not 100 precent understood so I would appreciate some explanation  on  changing a vector to a column vector representation
